# Sublime Text 2 - running selected python code in the interpreter

Tags: python, interpreter, sublimetext2

While editing a python script in the Sublime Text editor, I would like to run the script line by line, or block after block in the embedded interpreter.

Is there a convenient way how to do that? Perfect way for me would be:

1. select a few lines of code
2. hit a shortcut, which will run the selected code inside the interpreter

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two choices I think, one can be using PdbSublimeTextSupport, available here: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PdbSublimeTextSupport

Or you can try SublimeREPL, that can run Python code: https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL