# Send code to interactive python sublime text

Tags: python, sublimetext2

How does one sent highlighted code from *sublime text 2* editor to the interactive console started by going to *`view > show console`* in sublime text 2?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13495494/sublime-text-2-running-selected-python-code-in-the-interpreter

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are on Sublime Text 2 for a Mac, then press 'command' + 'B' to build.  If you are on Windows, then press 'Ctrl' + 'B'.

- Make sure to save your file with a .py extension (so your system will
  know to build in Python)
- Also check to make sure that your 'Tools' > 'Build System' > 'Automatic'

I hope I interpreted your question correctly.  If you're trying to make an interpreter on the console, you can use 'Package Control' to install SublimeREPL (https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL)

Edit: Showing the key control depending on what you want (e.g. just take the selection, the line, the entire file).  Screenshots are on a Windows 7 PC.

[image: After installing SublimeREPL, go to 'EVAL in REPL', and pick your selection]

[image: Here's evaluating just one line of python code]

Comment: I meant to ask about how can you send code with a key control to the interpreter without running all the code. Sometimes I would just like to run a single line of a page of code and copy and pasting is slow..

Comment: I added a couple pictures of how to use SublimeREPL.  You would start up a SublimeREPL that is Python, then depending on the amount of code you want to run, then do the 'Eval in REPL' shortcut (use the keyboard shortcut).  My picture is from a Windows PC.  Hopefully this helps with less copy/pasting.  Good luck!